# Get button response from popup window button click Jquery html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get click item from popup window by callback. example when i run below code  here show a popup window and here show subscribe  button. now how I know that click subscribe button or not  click ?

```js
function popitup(link)  {
    var w = window.open(
          link.href, 
          link.target||"_blank",
          menubar=no,
          toolbar=no,
          location=no,
          directories=no,
          status=no,
          scrollbars=no,
          resizable=no,
          dependent,
          width=800,
          height=620,
          left=0,
          top=0
    ); 
    return w?false:true;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCF_Xf8l8kspCPkgzhn5sYRw" onclick="return popitup(this)">
    Google
</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please format your code by editing your question

Comment: here is  i write only html code and show popup window by javascript.but I not clear how get subscribe button click.so I can't write the code.please give me tips how I do it?